# How to retrieve the Type field on the Event object?

Tags: deployment, ant

Type is a standard picklist field on the standard object Event and I want to retrieve the field as I made a modification to the picklist values but I am unable to retrieve it when I retrieve the event object and the when I retrieve it through the field I only get the metadata.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Standard Picklist can retrieved using StandardValueSet so for EventType your package.xml must have an entry like this

```
<types>
  <members>EventType</members>
  <name>StandardValueSet</name>
</types>
```

You can find name for Standard picklist from [Salesforce Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/standardvalueset_names.htm)